# Removing an observer in iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

i'm adding an observer in an NSObject class. And the app will be running 24X7. Since i'm not not removing the observer, app is getting crashed many times. So is there a way to fix this. Is it necessary to remove the observer in -(void)delloc method. Because if i remove the observer i can no longer get the notification. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please post the code you have used to add the observer, and explain what you are using NSNotificationCenter for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dealloc method, it's **absolutely necessary** to remove the observer.

If you want to keep getting the notifications, you should create an object that would never get `release-d/dealloc-ed`. Consider making a singleton object.

When you register for notifications, the object sends its reference. If the object has been release-d, app will crash.